# how to link multiple form in android eclipse?

Tags: android

**how to link multiple form in android eclipse?****Do i have to make multiple xml files in res/layout/main.xml and if this how to use them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make a quick explanation for you at your level of understanding. You will want to follow the tutorial Houcine gave you, but to answer your question best I can:

First off: A form is a field that users input information into. Like a textbox, or a checkbox. You CAN put multiple forms on a single page. For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RadioButton" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

See, all sorts of forms!

But I think what you mean to ask is, how do I link to different layouts.

The answer to your second question is: Yes! Simply make a new xml file in your res>layout folder! Toss a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top then have fun!

If you want to link to that new layout, make a button or something in main.xml. in the .xml file of that button, add `android:onClick="doThis"`  (or whatever you want in the quotations) to the button.

Now, make your second page (a new class) in the same directory as your main.java. Call it whatever you want. I'm going to call it Page2Activity.java.

Now, to switch between layouts easily as a beginner, I found this is the easiest way: Lets say our second page was page2.xml, add this piece of code into your main activity's java file.

```
    public void doThis(View view) {
    Intent page2 = new Intent();
    page2.setClassName("com.yourproject",
            "com.yourproject.page2Activity");
    startActivity(page2);
```

This should take you to the next class! Great huh? But we still need to use our page2.xml. You could use inflaters, (read up on those sometimes), but for beginner's sake just put

```
setContentView(R.layout.page2);
```

after

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

In your Page2Activity

ONE MORE THING: You have to add your new activity to your manifest! Easy peasy. Open up your AndroidManifest.xml, and add

```
<activity android:name=".Page2Activity"</activity>
```

right after the first  you see (which would be the main one)

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks Alot Vee I find my answer it helps me

Comment: Not a problem. Try to search more before asking questions next time. Don't forget to select the answer too!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are beginner , so my advice is to try to google your question and you will find your happyness , try this [tutorial](http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html) or this [one](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/) too  it is exactly what are you looking for :)